# How to add horizontal line after header and before footer?

Tags: header-footer, rules

How can I add horizontal line after header and before footer?

```
header
---------

---------
footer
```

Comment: I wonder what the solution for Plain TeX is.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your easiest approach here would be to include the [`fancyhdr` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) and set the header/footer rule widths using *`\renewcommand`*:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\pagestyle{fancy}% Change page style to fancy
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyhead[C]{Header}
\fancyfoot[C]{Footer}% \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Default \headrulewidth is 0.4pt
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Default \footrulewidth is 0pt
\begin{document}
Here is some text.
\end{document}
```

Headers and footers are simultaneously cleared using `\fancyhf{}`, and individually set using `\fancyhead[<pos>]{<stuff>}` and `\fancyfoot[<pos>]{<stuff>}`. See the [`fancyhdr` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf).

---

Modifying the colour of the header/footer rules is a bit more tricky, since `fancyhdr` doesn't supply this modification by default. [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) can be used to update the two rule macros `\headrule` and `\footrule` to insert the colour as needed. They are defined as follows:

```
\def\headrule{{\if@fancyplain\let\headrulewidth\plainheadrulewidth\fi
    \hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth \vskip-\headrulewidth}}

\def\footrule{{\if@fancyplain\let\footrulewidth\plainfootrulewidth\fi
    \vskip-\footruleskip\vskip-\footrulewidth
    \hrule\@width\headwidth\@height\footrulewidth\vskip\footruleskip}}
```

It is clear that the horizontal rule is drawn using `\hrule`, so we can patch these commands and insert `\color{<colour>}` just before drawing it by means of the following convenient helper macros:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox,fancyhdr,xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{etoolbox,fancyhdr,xcolor}
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\newcommand{\headrulecolor}[1]{\patchcmd{\headrule}{\hrule}{\color{#1}\hrule}{}{}}
\newcommand{\footrulecolor}[1]{\patchcmd{\footrule}{\hrule}{\color{#1}\hrule}{}{}}
```

This allows you to use `\headrulecolor{<colour>}` or `\footrulecolor{<colour>}` in order to change them individually. The above patch is standard for `etoolbox`, so see the [`etoolbox` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf) on how `\patchcmd` works. Here's a complete MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,fancyhdr,xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{etoolbox,fancyhdr,xcolor}
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\newcommand{\headrulecolor}[1]{\patchcmd{\headrule}{\hrule}{\color{#1}\hrule}{}{}}
\newcommand{\footrulecolor}[1]{\patchcmd{\footrule}{\hrule}{\color{#1}\hrule}{}{}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyhead[C]{Header}
\fancyfoot[C]{Footer}% \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Default \headrulewidth is 0.4pt
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Default \footrulewidth is 0pt
\headrulecolor{red!70}% Set header rule colour to 70% red.
\begin{document}
Here is some text.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

Here's another option using the [`titleps`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titleps) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titleps}

\newpagestyle{ruled}
{\sethead{}{Header}{}\headrule
  \setfoot{}{Footer}{}\footrule}
\pagestyle{ruled}

\begin{document}
Here is some text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Redefining `\makeheadrule` and `\makefootrule`, you can change the attributes; for example, to change the color:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titleps}

\newpagestyle{ruled}
{\sethead{}{Header}{}\headrule
  \setfoot{}{Footer}{}\footrule}
\pagestyle{ruled}

\renewcommand\makeheadrule{\color{cyan}\rule[-.3\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{0.4pt}}
\renewcommand\makefootrule{\color{cyan}\rule[\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{0.4pt}}

\begin{document}
Here is some text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can switch to other page style at any moment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titleps}

\newpagestyle{ruled}
{\sethead{}{Header}{}\headrule
  \setfoot{}{Footer}{}\footrule}
\pagestyle{ruled}

\begin{document}
Here is some text.\newpage
Here is some text.\newpage
\pagestyle{plain}
text
\end{document}
```

Comment: how can I adopt your code to add instead of 'footer' the number of page? Also, how can I replace 'header' with section name in the top left and chapter name in the top right?