# How to change the color of the header and footer horizontal lines?

Tags: header-footer, rules

I want to change the ***color of the lines (i think they are called "rules" in latex) after the heading and before the footer in every page*** of my report. I used these commands to add them but i couldn't change the color to gray

```
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
```

I used the package \color to (successfully) change the color of the headers and footers but it doesn't work inside the previous commands.

```
\color[rgb]{.55,.55,.55}
```

I also tried these codes which are for changing the colors of the tables, but it didn't work for my need

```
\usepackage{colortbl}
\arrayrulecolor{blue}\hline
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing exactly which lines are you talking about?

Comment: Did you saw related question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109153/how-to-add-horizontal-line-after-header-and-before-footer ? Duplicate?

Comment: Indeed Kurt. The answers in that question solved my problem. Thanks!