# How to add a line in the bottom of a page

Tags: line

Is there any way to add a line in the end of each page, with some texts?

I am looking for something like that

```
                               Main Text 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Text                         Number of page                          Text
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Run `texdoc fancyhdr`.

Comment: Do you use a KOMA-Script-class like scrreprt? Then use scrlayer-scrpage (see documentation of KOMA-Script) ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add horizontal line after header and before footer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109153/how-to-add-horizontal-line-after-header-and-before-footer)