# How can I add horizontal lines after the header and before the footer in koma-script classes?

Tags: koma-script, fancyhdr, scrlayer-scrpage

Consider this simple document.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\title{\Huge Me}
\author{Maulik}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\chapter{Introduction}
\blindtext[10]
\chapter{Methods}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I am using a KOMA-script class. In this document, I want to have horizontal lines after the header, and before the footer. It would look something like

```
header
--------
Text of the document
-------
footer
```

I know it can be done using fancyhdr package, along with renewcommand (as shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109153/how-to-add-horizontal-line-after-header-and-before-footer)). But is it possible to do the same using scrlayer-scrpage package, which is default in the KOMA-script classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For horizontal lines below the header and above the footer, just use the `headsepline` and `footsepline` options of `scrlayer-scrpage`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[headsepline, footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\title{\Huge Me}
\author{Maulik}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\chapter{Introduction}
\blindtext[10]
\chapter{Methods}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The KOMA-Script classes also provide options `headsepline` and `footsepline`. So in the example, you even would not need `scrlayer-scrpage`, if you'd move the options to `\documentclass`. The main difference with such lines in the classes and the packages is, that the package provides additional options `plainheadsepline` and `plainfootsepline` to configure the lines of the plain style. BTW: `\pagestyle{scrheadings}` is also not needed, because the page style is already active after loading the package …

Comment: … See also [How to insert a separator between header and text area](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/HowTo_HeadSepLine/) and [How to insert a separator between text area and footer](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/HowTo_FootSepLine/) in the [KOMA-Script Page Style HowTos](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/HowTo_PageHeadFoot/). The pages are also [available in German](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-de/HowTo_PageHeadFoot/)